# Why is there a line above the borderless setting in the Windows window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I use the user32.dll API all over Windows10
Set Borderless Window
After obtaining the focus, a border above will appear

```
win.SetWindowLong(m.Handle(), win.GWL_STYLE, uintptr(gwlStyle&^win.WS_CAPTION&^win.WS_BORDER|win.WS_THICKFRAME))
win.SetWindowPos(m.Handle(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, uint32(win.SWP_NOMOVE|win.SWP_NOSIZE|win.SWP_FRAMECHANGED))
```

**Questionable**
[image]

I hope it is a complete one without borders, but with a default shadow effect

**Desired effect**
[image]

Comment: How is gwlStyle initialized? And using XOR to disable bits may not be what you want either. It should be an AND with a inverted mask.

Comment: You add `win.WS_THICKFRAME` style at the end.

Comment: It's necessary to remove the window frame and caption items from your window by returning 0 without processing the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS rectangles which will cause the client area to resize to the size of the window, including the window frame. See [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize#remarks). Also, that does not affect frames that are adjusted using the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Windows style `WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME`, It's necessary to resolve `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message to [remove the standard frame by simply returning 0 when the wParam is TRUE which does not affect frames that are extended into the client area using the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize#remarks)

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME,
      0, 0, 300, 300, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   static const MARGINS shadow_state[2]{ { 0,0,0,0 },{ 1,1,1,1 } };
   ::DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &shadow_state[1]);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
        if (wParam == TRUE) {
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize#remarks
https://github.com/melak47/BorderlessWindow